# Grouping widget attributes in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

This is probably a simple question, but I can't find a solution anywhere online. I have been making a Kivy application and I keep on reiterating over the same attributes. Can I assign the widgets to groups, and then format the entire group?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can group widgets like you want, but you can specify attributes of widgets in a `.kv` file using [rules](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file) so those attributes don't have to be repeated every time.